# foxpro on ubuntu trusty

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, windows, window, aptitude

How can I (or is even possible to) run Visual FoxPro 6 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Please provide detailed installation instructions as I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! :-) Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn and refrain from using things like "Merry Christmas" as your question will remain on this site also outside the Christmas season...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Wine maybe? 
They were successfully running VFP 7:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=296

8 years ago there were issues with Windows dlls needed to be copied:
https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-users/2006-March/020756.html